# SQL Server xml parent child from same table. xml not sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a table `Messages` in SQL Server with the following columns:

```
ID,
DISPLAY_ACCT, 
parent_id, 
message_body,
time stamp
```

The `message_body` column contains XML and the `parent_id` links to the same table using id. This creates a parent child relationship. I need to aggregate the xml per name creating the following structure

```
<all_messages>
 <main_message timestamp="2023-04-01" id="12">
   <message_body> XML IN FIELD </message_body>
   <replies>
     <reply timestamp="2023-04-02" id="23">
       <message_body> XML IN FIELD </message_body>
     </reply>
     <reply timestamp="2023-04-01" id="22">
       <message_body> XML IN FIELD </message_body>
     </reply>
   </replies>
 </main_message>
</all_messages>
```

So the resulting record would be

```
DISPLAY_ACCT
111C111

Message
XML from above
```

I've tried

```
SELECT  
    DISPLAY_ACCT, 
    CAST(CAST((SELECT id as '@ID', 
                 timestamp AS '@timestamp', 
                 cast(msg_body as xml) MESSAGE_BODY 
            FROM [MESSAGES] AS [REPLY] 
               WHERE [REPLY].[parent_id] = [m1].[ID] 
               ORDER BY timestamp DESC FOR XML AUTO, TYPE, ELEMENTS ) AS [REPLIES] 
               FROM (select timestamp, 
          message_body
         from [MESSAGES]) [m1] 
        WHERE [m1].[parent_id] IS NULL AND [m1].[NAME] = [m2].[NAME] 
      ORDER BY timestamp FOR XML PATH ('MAIN_MESSAGE'), TYPE, ELEMENTS 
             ) AS varchar(max))  as varchar(max)) as xml_messages 
            FROM  [MESSAGES]  [m2]          
        GROUP BY DISPLAY_ACCT
```

which works for the most part but it won't sort by timestamp desc

Comment: Sample data would help immensely

Comment: Proper sample data, as in `CREATE TABLE` and some `INSERT` statements. Please [edit] your post and put that in

Comment: Also do you need to get recursive results ie replies to replies, or are all replies directy the chid of a single message?

Answer (score 1):

Your current query is self-joining a number of times, which is unnecessary. You only need one join. You can use `STRING_AGG` to aggregate (there is no `XML_AGG` unfortunately).

```sql
SELECT
  m.DISPLAY_ACCT,
  CAST(
    '<all_messages>' + 
    STRING_AGG(x.xml, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY m.timestamp DESC) +
    '</all_messages>'
  AS xml)
FROM Messages m
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      m.timestamp AS [@timestamp],
      m.id AS [@id],
      m.message_body,
      (
        SELECT
          r.timestamp AS [@timestamp],
          r.id AS [@id],
          r.message_body
        FROM Messages r
        WHERE r.parent_id = m.id
        ORDER BY
          r.timestamp DESC
        FOR XML PATH('reply'), ROOT('replies'), TYPE
      )
    FOR XML PATH('main_message')
) x(xml)
WHERE m.parent_id IS NULL
GROUP BY
  m.DISPLAY_ACCT;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/cu11LLfO)

If you need recursive replies then you would need a recursive CTE here.